# Zero out matrix higher diagonal using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let's say we have a n x n matrix. Taking n=4 as example:

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

This is what I want to achieve:

When cut=1, given from function parameter, the matrix becomes:

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x 0
```

When cut=3:

```
x x x x
x x x 0
x x 0 0
x 0 0 0
```

When cut=5:

```
x x 0 0
x 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

As we can see, the diagonal is being cut like a forward-slash, everything under the first slash would be zeros out.

I am using numpy's matrix facility to generate matrices, but I don't know how to code such algorithm. Any help please?

You can always assume this matrix will be an n x n matrix and cut < 2n - 1

Comment: Take a look at [triu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html). It does something similar, but in a different corner. You can tweak the matrix before and after `triu` to get the right results

Comment: Thanks, @Mathias711. As soon as I read through this doc, I knew that we could rotate matrix to its supported formation and rotate back. Thank you for help from all of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.tri`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html#numpy.tri) to generate a matrix that contains ones below a given diagonal and zeros above. Since you want the bottom-right corner zeroed out, we have to flip left and right:

```
bottom_right = lambda N, k: np.fliplr(np.tri(N, k=k-N)) == 1
```

For example, `bottom_right(4, 2)` creates the following boolean matrix:

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

You can use that as a slice to zero out the corner:

```
a = np.ones((4, 4))
a[bottom_right(4, 2)] = 0
```

`a` is now

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

**Another way:**

A one-liner based on [Mathias711's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230895/1071311):

```
f = lambda a, k: np.fliplr(np.triu(np.fliplr(a), k=k-a.shape[0]+1))
```

Comment: Guido kills a kitten every time you unnecessarily use `lambda` to write a function...

Answer (score 3):

```
a = np.array(range(16)).reshape((4,4))
b = np.array([list(i[::-1]) for i in a])
b = np.triu(b,-2)
b = np.array([list(i[::-1]) for i in b])
print b
```

yields:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14,  0]])
```

So, the `-2` in the `triu` corresponds to the `1` you want in the question. Make sure that the functions that will do this, corrects for this effect. I know it is not the most pythonic you'll ever encounter, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following simple function :

```
>>> def convertor(cut,array):
...     return np.flipud(np.tri(4,4,3-cut)).__mul__(array)
```

In this function i have create a matrix with the same dimension as your matrix with [np.tri](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html#numpy-tri) and [np.flipud](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html#numpy.flipud) functions.but its composed of 0 and 1 based on the result you want.For example for `cut = 2` you will have :

```
>>> np.flipud(np.tri(4,4,3-2))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

So now all you need it the multiplication of this matrix with yours! that we returned within our function!

Demo :

```
>>> m=array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
...          [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
...          [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
...          [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
>>> convertor(3,m)
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> convertor(0,m)
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
>>> convertor(1,m)
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  0.]])
>>> convertor(5,m)
array([[ 4.,  4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```